# .Net Framework Swagger Route Prefix

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

I have .Net framework project with WepApi 2. I'm trying to use Swagger. My SwaggerConfig.cs file at AppStart folder include this code block:

```cs
var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c => { c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "CustomerHelper.API");})
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c => { });
```

At first start, my route is like this: http://localhost:60151/ and I got HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.

When I change my route to http://localhost:60151/swagger/ui/index I can reach and use Swagger interface.

How can see directly Swagger interface at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set startup URL of your project. Right click project -> Properties -> Web -> specific page.

set it to  `swagger` should be fine.